# How to load multiple excel sheets into different tables using pentaho metadata injection

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have one excel file which is having 5 different sheets, i want to load all 5 sheets into different table using pentaho meta-data injection.

Note: I have implemented normal approach of repeating flow 5 times.

What i have tried

- 1) I have created another excel sheet with meta-data of all 5 sheets

  2) I am able to pass sheet-name as a run time variable and can able
  to replace it into sheets property

  3) I am stuck @ how to read
  corresponding meta-data file and replace into template.

Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: Do these 5 sheets always have the same name ?

Comment: Yes, it will have same name.

Comment: If they are fixed names, i don't see why you'd need to make the entire Metadata Injection templates and workflows. Read the file 5 times, one for each Sheet, with Metadata Injection the execution will be the same. If it's simple read and output to table, then it's much easier to read it 5 fixed times, it also makes it easier for maintenance in case you need to change the name of a sheet or layout.

Comment: I have already mentioned that i have that solution with me, i just want to create meta approach to make a generalised solution in-case sheet-name became dynamic and number of sheet increases.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed [Pentaho's example on how to use Metadata Injection](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.0/Products/Data_Integration/Transformation_Step_Reference/ETL_Metadata_Injection)? It also uses excel sheets to store metadata, and the name of the sheet is passed at runtime and applied by the use of a join.

In my experience, I've stored the metadata in a MySQL table and selected the corresponding one by the use of a Variable set in a previous transformation, depending on the format of the input file.

Comment: I have already gone through everything which is available on net, i think you did not read my question,however i have created a logic for my issue, i will share the answer in detail right up soon.

Comment: I had to read your question to try and help with an answer. The problem is your question is not very descriptive, so there are thing I had to imagine. Maybe you can re-formulate your question with more details regarding what you've already done and add some screenshots if necesary.